# filter url for everything between <p> </p> where <h2></h2> = value

Tags: html, url, parameters

Is it possible to create a url filter (www.website.com?filter=value) where the user could enter the data in the `<h2>` tag?

Example:

```
<p>
<h2>THIS</h2>
<div>information</div>
<h5>other info</h5>
<h2>THAT</h2>
<div>information2</div>
<h5>other info2</h5>
</p>
```

And to retrieve one section of the html the user would enter something similar to www.website.com?h2=THIS and only get back:

```
<h2>THIS</h2>
<div>information</div>
<h5>other info</h5>
```

Comment: To get data from h2, first you have to put it in h2, to get it you need  <input> tag html...

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried a form and had no results.

Comment: The user can't enter data directly in h2...Maybe I don't understand what you want.Can you put more info in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You will need some Javascript to achieve it.

```js
//Array of the elements you are wanting
const sections = [
  {
  title: 'THIS',
    info1: 'information',
    info2: 'other info'
  },
  {
   title: 'THAT',
    info1: 'information2',
    info2: 'other info2'
  }
]

//getting the URL and the parameters
var url_string = "http://www.website.com?h2=THIS"; //Can get this with window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var h2 = url.searchParams.get("h2");

//filtering through initial array and creating a new array based on the parameters value
let filteredSections = sections.filter((section) => {
 return section.title === h2
})

//Looping through the filtered array, creating each element and displaying it to HTML by appending it
filteredSections.forEach((section) => {
 let wrappingDiv = document.createElement('div')
  
  let h1Tag = document.createElement('h1')
  h1Tag.textContent = section.title
  
  let innerDiv = document.createElement('div')
  innerDiv.textContent = section.info1
  
  let h5Tag = document.createElement('h5')
  h5Tag.textContent = section.info2
  
  let bodyTag = document.querySelector('body')
  
  //appending everything in html
  bodyTag.appendChild(wrappingDiv)
  wrappingDiv.appendChild(h1Tag)
  wrappingDiv.appendChild(innerDiv)
  wrappingDiv.appendChild(h5Tag)
})
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Javascript will create elements here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have a question about any of it